# Why does a singular distribution have its derivative zero almost everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $m$ be the Lebesgue measure ans $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a monotonically increasing continuous function such that $\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=1$.

Let $m_F$ be the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure associated with $F$.

If $m_F$ is singular with respect to $m$ then $F’=0$ $m$-a.e.? How do I prove this? Any reference?

Since $F$ is monotonically increasing, $F$ is differentiable $m$-a.e. So $F’$ is well-defined here. Since $m_F$ is singular with respect to $m$, there exists a Borel set $A$ such that $m_F(A)=0$ and $m(A^c)=0$. I think this implies that $F$ is almost every locally constant on $A$, but I cannot prove this. How do I prove this?

> My definition for “$m_F$ is singular with respect to $m$” is that there exists a Borel set $A$ such that $m_F(A)=0$ and $m(A^c)=0$.

Comment: This is basically just the definition of "singular" in this setting. If it is not, then you subtract off the corresponding absolutely continuous part to get the singular part. If you have another definition then please state it so that we can prove the two are equivalent.

Comment: Well, my definition for “$m_F\perp m$” is as follows: there exists a Borel set $A$ such that $m_F(A)=0$ and $m(A^c)=0$.

Comment: As you said, some texts define $m_F\perp m$ as the condition that $F’=0$ $m$-a.e.. These must be equivalent, but I don’t see why. And this is my question.

Comment: Yes I understand the question now. For such a question it is helpful if you state your definition so that it is clear what is to be proven and what is to be assumed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $F'>0$ on some $A$ with $m(A)>0$, one can show that then $m_F(A)>0$. So $m_F$ and $m$ are not singular wrt to one another. To prove that intermediate statement, "foliate" $A$ into $A_n$ with $F'>1/n$ on $A_n$. One of the $A_n$ must have positive $m$-measure and for this one the desired inequality is easily seen.

Comment: I do not get it. I understand we can take $A_n$ such that $F’>1/n$ on $A_n$ and $m(A_n)>0$. However, why does this imply that $m_F(A)>0$?

Comment: @Rubertos Because $m_F(A) \geq \int_A F'(x) dm(x) \geq m(A_n)/n>0$. This is easiest to see when $A=(a,b]$ so that that $m_F(A)=F(b)-F(a)$.